# How to get a class values in the variable?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have code of table where in one field I used class="errorwidth" and other is class="error". I want to get these classes values in  the variable. & these classes values changed on the the table columns with different numeric values

```
<td class="error" style="color:red"></td><td class="errorwidth" style="color:red"></td>
```

here is the code that I'm trying to get classes data this one "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk" in the variable

```
var error = $(this).val();
  var errorOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'error') ? error : false;   

            var errorwidth = $(this).val();
  var errorwidthOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'errorwidth') ? errorwidth : false;    

                so that i can use that variables here in this code:


if (grandTotal > 7 && errorwidthOnly != "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk" && errorOnly != "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk") {
                    $('#result').html('FCL');
                } else if (grandTotal < 7 && errorwidthOnly != "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk" && errorOnly != "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk") {
                    $('#result').html('LCL');
                }
                else if((grandTotal > 7 || grandTotal < 7) && errorwidthOnly == "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk" || errorOnly == "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk" || errorOnly != "Cargo won't fit in 20STD and 40STD Containers, change the mode to bulk")
                {
                $('#result').html('BULK');
            }
```

Comment: `$('.errorwidth').text()` or `$('.errorwidth').html();`?

Comment: actually $('.errorwidth') have text values but grandTotal has numeric/decimal value & both of their result needs to display in one single id ('#result')

Answer (score 0):

You should try with `text()` because `div` always contain text as value so `val()` is not work in you case.

```
var error = $(".error").text();// change here
  var errorOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'error') ? error : false;   

            var errorwidth = $(".errorwidth").text();//Change Here
  var errorwidthOnly = ($(this).attr('class') == 'errorwidth') ? errorwidth : false;    

                so that i can use that variables here in this code:


if (grandTotal > 7 && errorwidthOnly != "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk" && errorOnly != "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk") {
                    $('#result').html('FCL');
                } else if (grandTotal < 7 && errorwidthOnly != "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk" && errorOnly != "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk") {
                    $('#result').html('LCL');
                }
                else if((grandTotal > 7 || grandTotal < 7) && errorwidthOnly == "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk" || errorOnly == "Cargo won't fit in 20STD, 40STD and 40HC Containers, change the mode to bulk" || errorOnly != "Cargo won't fit in 20STD and 40STD Containers, change the mode to bulk")
                {
                $('#result').html('BULK');
            }
```

Comment: sorry i make change in my code but its not working. that classes error & errorwidth values displayed in the table field <td>. & can you please tell me that how can i check that variables values that is it getting correct values or not . like in php we use <?php echo $ variablename ?> & with this line of code we can check easily that our value is correct .please try again
Regards Ankit

Comment: what happen if you use class name as selector ? @Ankit I have change my code so please try now

Comment: `var error = $(".error").text();` and  `var errorwidth = $(".errorwidth").text();`

Comment: no its not displaying me bulk nowhere please check again Regards Ankit

Comment: here is the link you can check here functionality

Comment: @Ankit i can not get your link. :(

Comment: are you checking solution for me Mayank ?

Comment: Yes! I will check and revert to u @Ankit

Comment: Mayank are you checking solution ?

Comment: Yes have checked there are many errors when we change values in textbox errors like function not define

Comment: Mayank that all are just warning's red in color. & where you can see LCL/FCL on the m3 columns result. there in place of LCL/FCL i need to display BULK if that warning message displayed & lcl displayed if m3 totals result is < 7 & FCl if > 7 & bulk should be on if warning message is there that time wheather the FCl & LCL condition is true but that will not follow if there will be warning message need only BULK. please get that correct & Reply me asap, I am waiting here.Thanks & Regards - Ankit

Comment: I checked when I tried with class name as selector then it is working. But You should traversal method of jquery to reach class `error` and `errorwith`

Comment: ok  is it working with both height & width means classes error & errorwidth ?

& can you please show me the demo so i can check that please & may be able to tell you if something required .
Regards - Ankit

Comment: Ok PLease  make one demo in jsfiddle send the link. So we can help you in better way

Comment: ok Mayank i make fiddle & write all code of test page in that but the code is not working there in the fiddle link : https://fiddle.jshell.net/Nehacue/rcqzs5m8/1/ 
please check Regards - Ankit